# Why is $scope >= 0 showing true in interpolation while empty in controller?

Tags: angularjs, boolean, angularjs-scope, logical-operators

I'm setting a `$scope` variable to `0` or `1` based on a successful action and showing elements with ng-show. I'm resetting the `$scope` variable to empty when the step is finished. However, I have discovered that `$scope = ''` is shown as `true` if in interpolation `{{$scope >= 0}}`. Why not false?

```
controllers.Ctrl = function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $filter, ajax, $parse) {

$scope.datachanged = '';
console.log($scope.datachanged >= 0); // true

};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just javascript for you. `'' >= 0` will evaluate to `true`. This is because the empty string `''` is falsy, and so is 0, so you can think of it as `false >= false`.

Instead, why don't you **reset the variable to `undefined`** (ie `$scope.datachanged = undefined`). `undefined >= 0` will evaluate to `false`.

Alternatively, if the variable will only be set to 0 or 1, you could also just check to see if your variable equals 1 where you do the interpolation. `{{datachanged === 1}`